# One printer, two printer entries (no cups are being used, but only one entry actually works)

Tags: linux-mint, printer

I have one network printer attached to my system. I am having trouble because having this one printer creates two entries in print dialog boxes in (some!) applications.

The system "Printers" control panel is pictured below.
*Firefox, LibreOffice all have this (and only this) printer in their print dialog boxes (which is correct).*

[image]

Other applications (such as the Text Editor, etc.) use the print dialog box pictured below.
***The one with underscores works just fine** -- yes, there is a silly extra underscore on the right-hand side for no discernable reason, but everything seems to work OK*
***The one with dashes does NOT work at all** -- despite the status of "Printer is ready to print", the only clue that something is wrong is that the "Advanced" tab disappears; also, if used, raw data or something is sent to the printer & many pages of glyphs come spewing out -- which is a problem because this is my wife's lappy, and sometimes she picks the wrong one, and it is difficult to cancel the job).*

I never installed any drivers for this printer (everything was automatically added by the distro).
If the printer is removed, it will automatically be added again (and I like that printers are auto-detected, that is great).

What I would like to know is: **is there any way to hide the one rogue, troublesome entry?**

Using Linux Mint 20.3 Una

*As an aside, other distros running on my home network (Debian 11 and Fedora) also detect this network printer, but do not exhibit the problem with two entries: only the good printer with the underscores in the name is detected and shown in application printer dialogues.*

---

***Good entry:***
[image]

***Rogue, troublesome entry:***
[image]